# Excel does not consider a cell as Blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formatting

I would like to define a function or formatting such that the "COUNTBLANK()" excel function does not consider as blank a "grey-cell", where the user is not allowed to type anything.

For example, let's suppose there is a balance sheet statement, where in cell C3 there is a "grey colored cell", in order to indicate to the user that she is not allowed to text or digit anything inside cell C3, including "0$" nor "-$".

Let's suppose in cell C100 there is a COUNTBLANK(C2:C99) function, in order to check if there are any missing values in the C-column. The function will return COUNTBLANK(C2:C99)=1, as in cell C3 the user did not text or digit anything. However, the C3 cell is "grey colored" and must be empty, and therefore not considered as missing (by definition).

Is there any function/formatting?

Comment: Couldn't you just pre-populate those cells with a space or other non-visible character?

Comment: Are the cells just grey or are they really protected?

Comment: If you know in advance how many cells are _grey_  then just subtract this number from `COUNTBLANK(C2:C99)` or exclude all the ranges which should not be counted. Otherwise when is a cell _grey_ and what happens if a user enters data anyway?

Comment: If you have (say 5 grey cells) just use `=COUNTBLANK(C2:C99)-5`

Comment: Sorry @Storax, didn't ready your comment before posting mine :)

Comment: @Super Symmetry: no problem

Comment: @roy the cell are not protected, just grey, so I will add a space and protect themThanks a lot

Comment: Just my humble opinion: Adding spaces in this manner is very bad design and just asking for trouble in the near future when you have forgotten you have done so or you have other people working with you on the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next function, please:

```
Function CountBlkGray(rng As Range) As Long
   Dim lngGray As Long, c As Range
   For Each c In rng
    If c.Value = "" And (c.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 Or _
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Or c.Interior.ColorIndex = 48 Or _
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 16) Then lngGray = lngGray + 1
   Next
   CountBlkGray = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) - lngGray
End Function
```

You can simple use it like formula:

```
=CountBlkGray(A1:A16)
```

It will consider gray cells as not blank ones...

But you must use the standard Gray colors (from Excel available Pallete)